# Pair de vector c++

Tags: c++

Eu implementei o caixeiro viajante e mostro o custo mínimo de todos os caminhos. Agora eu quero mostrar o caminho que corresponde ao menor custo. 
Estou usando para fazer isso um `pair<int, vector<int> > x`, onde como first eu coloco o custo mínimo e no second eu coloco meu vector de caminho.

Quando eu coloco `x.make_pair(custoMinimo, push_back(caminho))`, ele dá o erro:

```
struct std::pair<int, std::vector<int> >’ has no member named ‘make_pair’
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como arrumar isso?

Answer (score 2):

`make_pair` nao e um metodo da instancia `x`, e um metodo que retorna um par. Logo, voce precisa usar assim:

```
x = make_pair(custoMinimo, push_back(caminho))
```

Comment: Deu certo aqui Lucas, valeu !
Deixa eu só perguntar outra coisa, como eu varreria esse pair de vector ? 
Como o size não faz parte de pair, como que faria ?

Comment: E um par usual, entao `x.first` e um inteiro e `x.second` e um vetor. Entao voce pode fazer algo como `for (auto &it : x.second) cout << it << endl;` ou algo assim para imprimir os inteiros no vetor.

Comment: @user15930 se a resposta lhe atende pode marcar como "Aceita", clicando na marca de verificação ao lado da resposta (em forma de V). Mais informações aqui: [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/3117)

Comment: deu certo, valeu Lucas !

Comment: so um detalhe, @user15930, eu usei algumas coisas do padrao 'recente' de c++, netao talvez nao funcione em compiladores antigos.